# filter select boxes based on value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have select box three level of select box, and I want when user select first selection the second selection display only the data related to the first selection and when user select the second selection the last SELECT BOX only display the data related to the second selection.

```js
$("#select1").change(function() {
  if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
    $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
  }
  var id = $(this).val();
  var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
  $('#select2').html(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="region">
  <option value="1">Region 1</option>
  <option value="2">Region 2</option>
  <option value="3">Region 3</option>
</select>

<select id="City">
  <option value="1">City1</option>
  <option value="1">City1</option>
  <option value="1">City1</option>
  <option value="2">City2</option>
  <option value="2">City2</option>
  <option value="3">City3</option>
  <option value="2">City2</option>
  <option value="3">City3</option>
  <option value="1">City1</option>
</select>

<select id="barangay">
  <option value="city1">barangay1</option>
  <option value="city2">barangay1city2</option>
  <option value="city3">barangay1city3</option>
  <option value="city3">barangay1city3</option>
  <option value="city3">barangay1city3</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1city1</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1city1</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1city1</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1city1</option>
</select>
```

it works like this but this is only two level of select box filter

and to tell you honestly I have only very basic understanding of jquery and how it works. hopefully someone guide me in the right way.

Comment: thank's for the comment my bad i edit it "value" is the right one, sorry and thank's

Comment: I would have a different select for every selection you want to refer to. Then just change the `display`.

Comment: just like sample fiddle above but in my case i want it to make it three selection if they select on "region" the select "city" only display belong to that region and the select "barangay" disply only when user select his/her "City" and data display only belong to the city he/she select, hope this help

Comment: thank you everyone, your answer is all helpful, anyway this is my update fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/4c923p6u/3/ the region and city is already working, I just want is, when user select one of the city listed on select the barangay under that city will display. hope this help

Comment: @jhunlio Ask a new question then. And stop posting jSFiddle links, instead include your code as a runnable snippet in the question itself.

Comment: ok connexo thank's for the tips will do, thank you very much..

Answer (score 1):

This might help you.

```
<select id="region">
  <option value="" selected>Select region</option>
  <option value="1">Region 1</option>
  <option value="2">Region 2</option>
  <option value="3">Region 3</option>
</select>

<select id="City">
  <option value="">Select City</option>
  <option value="1">City1</option>
  <option value="1">City1</option>
  <option value="1">City1</option>
  <option value="2">City2</option>
  <option value="2">City2</option>
  <option value="3">City3</option>
  <option value="2">City2</option>
  <option value="3">City3</option>
  <option value="1">City1</option>
</select>

<select id="barangay">
  <option value="">Select barangay</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1</option>
  <option value="city2">barangay1city2</option>
  <option value="city3">barangay1city3</option>
  <option value="city3">barangay1city3</option>
  <option value="city3">barangay1city3</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1city1</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1city1</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1city1</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1city1</option>
</select>
```

Script

```
$("#region").change(function(){
    var val=$(this).val();
    $("#City option").hide();
  $("#City").val("");
    $("#City option[value='"+val+"']").show();
  $("#City").change();
});

$("#City").change(function(){
    var val=$(this).val();
    $("#barangay option").hide();
  $("#barangay").val("");
    $("#barangay option[value='city"+val+"']").show();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c47so2jq/

Comment: thank you very much RV, is that posible to change the the default value of city to blank so that the user select first the city before the barangay appear.

Comment: *This might help you* as the only non-code text is guaranteed to get you downvotes. Mine you have.

Comment: @connexo. Thank you. But atleast there is no bug like yours code have. I just tested your code. Select region then city. and then change region again. doesnt get back to original. that will get you downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `change` listener to the first two `select` elements, then iterate over each `option` of the next `select` and decide whether it should be displayed or not. I'm using the `hidden` property/attribute for this in my example.

As usual, this is easy to do without the help of any external library like jQuery.

Here you go in plain vanilla Javascript (ES6):

```js
region.addEventListener('change', ({target: el}) => {
    [...city.options].forEach((option) => {
      option.hidden = !(option.value === el.value) && !option.disabled;
    })
})

city.addEventListener('change', ({target: el}) => {
    [...barangay.options].forEach((option) => {
      option.hidden = !(option.value === `city${el.value}`) && !option.disabled;
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="region">
  <option disabled selected>Pick a region</option>
  <option value="1">Region 1</option>
  <option value="2">Region 2</option>
  <option value="3">Region 3</option>
</select>

<select id="city">
  <option disabled selected>Pick a city</option>
  <option value="1">City1</option>
  <option value="1">City1</option>
  <option value="1">City1</option>
  <option value="2">City2</option>
  <option value="2">City2</option>
  <option value="3">City3</option>
  <option value="2">City2</option>
  <option value="3">City3</option>
  <option value="1">City1</option>
</select>

<select id="barangay">
  <option disabled selected>Pick a barangay</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1</option>
  <option value="city2">barangay1city2</option>
  <option value="city3">barangay1city3</option>
  <option value="city3">barangay1city3</option>
  <option value="city3">barangay1city3</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1city1</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1city1</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1city1</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1city1</option>
</select>
```

If you need to also reset the value of an already picked city if region is changed, here you go:

```js
region.addEventListener('change', ({target: el}) => {
    [...city.options].forEach((option) => {
      option.hidden = !(option.value === el.value) && !option.disabled;
    })
    city.value = 'default';
    barangay.value = 'default';
})

city.addEventListener('change', ({target: el}) => {
    [...barangay.options].forEach((option) => {
      option.hidden = !(option.value === `city${el.value}`) && !option.disabled;
    })
    barangay.value = 'default';
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="region">
  <option disabled selected value="default">Pick a region</option>
  <option value="1">Region 1</option>
  <option value="2">Region 2</option>
  <option value="3">Region 3</option>
</select>

<select id="city">
  <option disabled selected value="default">Pick a city</option>
  <option value="1">City1</option>
  <option value="1">City1</option>
  <option value="1">City1</option>
  <option value="2">City2</option>
  <option value="2">City2</option>
  <option value="3">City3</option>
  <option value="2">City2</option>
  <option value="3">City3</option>
  <option value="1">City1</option>
</select>

<select id="barangay">
  <option disabled selected value="default">Pick a barangay</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1</option>
  <option value="city2">barangay1city2</option>
  <option value="city3">barangay1city3</option>
  <option value="city3">barangay1city3</option>
  <option value="city3">barangay1city3</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1city1</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1city1</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1city1</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1city1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: select region first, then select city, and then change region again. does city changes to default?? that's what issue is

Comment: Yes, it does change. OP has not stated a requirement that *value* of select needs to be changed, only the *available* options.

Comment: @RV Added a second example for that hypothetical requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking to work so?

```js
 $("#region").change(function () {
     if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
         $(this).data('options', $('#City option').clone());
     }
     var id = $(this).val();
     var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
     $('#City').html(options);
 });
 
  $("#City").change(function () {
     if ($(this).data('options') == undefined) {
         $(this).data('options', $('#barangay option').clone());
     }
     var id = $(this).val();
     var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=city' + id + ']');
     $('#barangay').html(options);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="region">
  <option value="1">Region 1</option>
  <option value="2">Region 2</option>
  <option value="3">Region 3</option>
</select>

<select id="City">
  <option value="1">City1</option>
  <option value="1">City1</option>
  <option value="1">City1</option>
  <option value="2">City2</option>
  <option value="2">City2</option>
  <option value="3">City3</option>
  <option value="2">City2</option>
  <option value="3">City3</option>
  <option value="1">City1</option>
</select>

<select id="barangay">
  <option value="city1">barangay1</option>
  <option value="city2">barangay1city2</option>
  <option value="city3">barangay1city3</option>
  <option value="city3">barangay1city3</option>
  <option value="city3">barangay1city3</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1city1</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1city1</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1city1</option>
  <option value="city1">barangay1city1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Changing region is not changing city.

Answer (score 0):

Read my comment, then:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
var doc, bod, M, T, I, S, Q, aC, rC; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', function(){
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
M = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
T = function(tag){
  return doc.getElementsByTagName(tag);
}
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
S = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
aC = function(element, className){
  var s = element.className.split(/\s+/), n = s.indexOf(className);
  if(n === -1){
    s.push(className); element.className = s.join(' ').trim();
  }
  return function(className, text){
    return aC(element, className, text);
  }
}
rC = function(element, className){
  var s = element.className.split(/\s+/), n = s.indexOf(className);
  if(n !== -1){
    s.splice(n, 1); element.className = s.join(' ').trim();
  }
  return function(className, text){
    return rC(element, className, text);
  }
}
var cities = Q('.city'), hoods = Q('.neighborhood');
function hideHoods(){
  for(var i=0,l=hoods.length; i<l; i++){
    aC(hoods[i], 'hide')
  }
}
I('region').onchange = function(){
  for(var i=0,d,l=cities.length; i<l; i++){
    aC(cities[i], 'hide')
  }
  d = cities[this.selectedIndex];
  rC(d, 'hide'); hideHoods(); rC(I(d.value), 'hide');
}
for(var i=0,d,l=cities.length; i<l; i++){
  d = cities[i];
  d.onchange = function(){
    hideHoods(); rC(I(this.value), 'hide');
  }
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
#content{
  padding:7px;
}
label{
  display:inline-block; margin-bottom:3px;
}
select{
  width:100%; padding:3px 5px; margin-bottom:5px;
}
.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='content'>
    <label>Region</label>
    <select id='region'>
      <option value='east' selected='selected'>east</option>
      <option value='central'>central</option>
      <option value='west'>west</option>
    </select>
    <label>City</label>
    <select id='east' class='city'>
      <option value='Boston' selected='selected'>Boston</option>
      <option value='NY'>New York</option>
      <option value='Philadelphia'>Philadelphia</option>
    </select>
    <select id='central' class='hide city'>
      <option value='Minneapolis' selected='selected'>Minneapolis</option>
      <option value='Milwaukee'>Milwaukee</option>
      <option value='Chicago'>Chicago</option>
    </select>
    <select id='west' class='hide city'>
      <option value='Seattle' selected='selected'>Seattle</option>
      <option value='Portland'>Portland</option>
      <option value='SanFran'>San Francisco</option>
    </select> 
    <label>Neighborhood</label>
    <select id='Boston' class='neighborhood'>
      <option value='Allston' selected='selected'>Allston</option>
      <option value='Back Bay'>Back Bay</option>
      <option value='Bay Village'>Bay Village</option>
    </select>
    <select id='NY' class='hide neighborhood'>
      <option value='Harlem' selected='selected'>Harlem</option>
      <option value='SoHo'>SoHo</option>
      <option value='Lower East Side'>Lower East Side</option>
    </select>
    <select id='Philadelphia' class='hide neighborhood'>
      <option value='French Quarter' selected='selected'>French Quarter</option>
      <option value='Logan Square'>Logan Square</option>
      <option value='Old City'>Old City</option>
    </select>
    <select id='Minneapolis' class='hide neighborhood'>
      <option value='Downtown West' selected='selected'>Downtown West</option>
      <option value='Howe'>Howe</option>
      <option value='Hawthorne'>Hawthorne</option>
    </select>
    <select id='Milwaukee' class='hide neighborhood'>
      <option value='Riverwest' selected='selected'>Riverwest</option>
      <option value='East Town'>East Town</option>
      <option value='Historic Third Ward'>Historic Third Ward</option>
    </select>
    <select id='Chicago' class='hide neighborhood'>
      <option value='Lincoln Park' selected='selected'>Lincoln Park</option>
      <option value='Wicker Park'>Wicker Park</option>
      <option value='Edgewater'>EdgeWater</option>
    </select>
    <select id='Seattle' class='hide neighborhood'>
      <option value='Greenwood' selected='selected'>Greenwood</option>
      <option value='Wallingford'>Wallingford</option>
      <option value='Fremont'>Fremont</option>
    </select>
    <select id='Portland' class='hide neighborhood'>
      <option value='Mount Tabor' selected='selected'>Mount Tabor</option>
      <option value='Downtown'>Downtown</option>
      <option value='Goose Hollow'>Goose Hollow</option>
    </select>
    <select id='SanFran' class='hide neighborhood'>
      <option value='Haight-Ashbury' selected='selected'>Haight-Ashbury</option>
      <option value='Chinatown'>Downtown</option>
      <option value='Mission Bay'>Mission Bay</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This just shows simple technique. I would actually create Object Oriented code that is fully expandable, in practice.

Comment: You always obfuscate your code like that? :D Also, putting each option group in their own `select` element is unnecessary and imo, bad.

Comment: That's a horrible idea. `<optgroup>` needs a label attribute to look decent. So, there would be extra text or an empty space. Not to mention, if this got bigger there would be too much clutter.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough - I was referring to option group in a semantical sense (options that share the same `value`), not about the `optgroup` element.